# Regex in python doesn't match anything

Tags: python, regex

I have this piece of code just for testing regular expressions in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

line = "(400,71.20,73.40) Cats are smarter than dogs"

matchObj = re.match( r'(\d{3}),(\d{2}.\d{2}),(\d{2}.\d{2})', line,re.I)

if matchObj:
   print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group()
   print "matchObj.group(1) : ", matchObj.group(1)
   print "matchObj.group(2) : ", matchObj.group(2)
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

It's supposed to print 3 groups `(400)(71.20)(73.40)`, but instead always prints `"No Match!!"`.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could try an online regex site like https://regex101.com/#python to debug your code

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the function `re.match` which tries to match from the start of the string. Since there is an unmatched `(` present at the start, your regex fails. So adding a pattern to match the starting `(` symbol in `re.match` will solves your problem.

```
re.match( r'\((\d{3}),(\d{2}\.\d{2}),(\d{2}\.\d{2})', line)
```

And also `re.I` is unneceassry here since we are matching chars other than alphabets.

**or**

I suggest you to use `re.search` to match a substring which exists anywhere.

```
re.search( r'(\d{3}),(\d{2}\.\d{2}),(\d{2}\.\d{2})', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include `\(` in your regex as `match` matches from beginning and your string has `(` as start.

or simply use `re.findall`

```
line = "(400,71.20,73.40) Cats are smarter than dogs"

matchObj = re.findall( r'\((\d{3}),(\d{2}\.\d{2}),(\d{2}\.\d{2})', line)
print matchObj
```

OUTPUT: `[('400', '71.20', '73.40')]`